# On test execute how can i select a different testcase that is present in my test suite?

Tags: testcomplete

I have 2 different test cases written in my test suite in test complete. Regression and preformance. Now am trying to run performance test case through test execute, but by default only regression test case gets executed. How can i change this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [command line-parameters of TestExecute](http://smartbear.com/viewarticle/90518/) in order to specify a project or even script routine to run. For example:

> ...\TestExecute.exe c:\tests\MySuite\MySuite.pjs
>   /project:PerfomanceProject **/unit:Unit1 /routine:runTest** /run /exit
>   /silentmode

or

> ...\TestExecute.exe c:\tests\MySuite\MySuite.pjs
>   /project:PerfomanceProject **/test:"KeywordTests|MainTest"** /run /exit
>   /silentmode